# Index DateTimeField in django by year, month, day, hour

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I use django 1.10 with PostgresSQL DB.

I have a table with millions and in the future billions of records. Each record has a DateTimeField as a timestamp. Obviously, querying this table is very long and therefore needs some indexing, which I have on several fields (not on the timestamp), but when I need to count all the records in a specific timeframe, the indexing is not helpful.

I wonder if django has a smart built-in way to index a DateTimeField based on year, month, day, hour resolutions. Or do I have to separate the timestamp field to multiple fields for every resolution, and then to index each of them?

### UPDATE:

The table is for saving clicks attributes so say for every click I have an id, source, timestamp, user_device, price and is_success attributes.

Now, given a certain timeframe I'd like to-

1) count all the clicks generated in that timeframe.

2) count all the successful ones in that timeframe.

3) sum the prices of all the successful ones in that timeframe.

4) optionally group by one or more of- source, user_device, year, month, day, hour.

1 is the problem. for 2,3 I have an index and 4 is not that heavy.

Thanks!

Comment: Please give some example data and what exactly you want to query on it.

Comment: @KlausD. Added! Let me know if you need any more data

Comment: While grouping is a little more tricky with the Django ORM, 1) - 4) can be done easily with a `filter()` and a normal index on the `DataTimeField`.

Comment: @KlausD. But wouldn't indexing DateTimeField create an enormous, inefficient index table? Which in turn will hurt the inserts more than a usual index?

Comment: Explain your assumption!

Comment: @KlausD. Postgres `DateTimeField` has  a microsecond-based resolution, and I need only an hour-based resolution, which means the index table will have lots of useless rows for my usage.

Comment: That's not how indexes in PostgreSQL work.

Comment: @KlausD. I'd love if you could explain how does it work because I didn't find any relevant data on the subject prior to asking the question. But any how, thank you!